# Specific position of icon in Container with BoxDecoration and child: Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I am trying to move the red block to the right of the `Container`. I have tried many variations but no matter where I move the code, that "red container" bit, I cannot get it to the position on the top right. I will make it a clickable icon when I get the positioning right.

I did move it into the children Widget with the other Text, adjusted the "crossAxisAlignment to stretch in that row, and mainAxisAlignment to spaceBetween,"

The closest I have is the 2nd image which is the code added below.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

```
items.add(
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12,spreadRadius: 2.0,blurRadius: 5.0),]),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Image.asset(object["personImage"],
                  width: 80,height: 80,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue[900],
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 0, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(object["personName"]),
                      Text(object["personPlace"]),
                      Text(object["personDate"]),
                      Text(object["personCircle"]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                height: 42.0,
                width: 42.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  return items;
```

---

Edit: So **two** solutions that worked out great. Adding a widget between blue and red containers. Thanks to you both: :)

T.T Sage » `Spacer(),`

Viren V Varasadiya » `Expanded(child: Container()),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a widget called `Spacer()` for this.

The `Spacer` widget takes up space that isn't used by the rest of your widget. Check the code below, it works fine:

```
items.add(
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12,spreadRadius: 2.0,blurRadius: 5.0),]),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Image.asset(object["personImage"],
                  width: 80,height: 80,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue[900],
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 0, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(object["personName"]),
                      Text(object["personPlace"]),
                      Text(object["personDate"]),
                      Text(object["personCircle"]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // add your spacer widget here
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                height: 42.0,
                width: 42.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  return items;
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Expanded widget to do so.

In following code i show how to add Expanded widget and where yo add.

```
Container(
            color: Colors.blue[900],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(object["personName"]),
                  Text(object["personPlace"]),
                  Text(object["personDate"]),
                  Text(object["personCircle"]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container()),  // added widget
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            height: 42.0,
            width: 42.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
```

Comment: That worked a treat - thank you :) -  Expanded(child: Container()),